# Передать файл в переменную через POST, Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

На странице есть небольшая форма:

```
<form method='post'><textarea name='xml' cols=70 rows=20></textarea><input type='submit'></form>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="input" accept="xml" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Вопрос: как с помощью `POST`-запроса передать файл в переменную `xml`? Пользуюсь библиотекой `Retrofit 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс с описанием метода отправки xml будет примерно таким:

```
public interface FormService {  
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("form.php")
    Call<Void> createTask(@Field("xml") String xml);
}
```

Что с ним делать думаю вы уже должны знать раз уже пользуетесь ретрофитом.